# Opencv using drawcontours to display contours,but get blank window

Tags: opencv

I want to display some contours from a set of contours,but I just got blank window.My code:

```
……………………………………
vector<vector<Point>> curvePointSet1;//contours from image1;
vector<vector<Point>> curvePointSet2;contours from image2;
vector<Point> curveMathcePair;//matched contour(curve) pairs,(x,y) stand for corresponding curves from image1 and image2 

Mat img1 = Mat( Size( 640, 480 ), CV_8U ,Scalar(0));
Mat img2 = Mat( Size( 640, 480 ), CV_8U ,Scalar(0));

for (int i = 0; i < curveMathcePair.size();i++)
{
    vector<vector<Point>> curveTemp1, curveTemp2;
    curveTemp1.push_back( curvePointSet1[curveMathcePair[i].x] );//curveMathcePair[i].x stand for curve form image1,and its corresponding curve form image2 denote as curveMathcePair[i].y;
    curveTemp2.push_back( curvePointSet2[curveMathcePair[i].y] );
    drawContours( img1, curveTemp1,0, Scalar(255),1 );
    drawContours( img2, curveTemp2,0, Scalar(255),1 );
}
imshow( "img1", img1 );
imshow( "img2", img2 );
```

Comment: My goal is to display the corresponding curves(matched curve pairs) in windows.

Comment: I'm can't see where your curvePointSet1 and curvePointSet2 filled with contours. Are you feel these vectors in other place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the reason.In the code above,there is no error.The reason why I got the blank windows is that I used Visual Studio 2013 to compile the code,but my OpenCV is suitable for Visual Studio 2010.Sorry for my mistake.Go to Project - Properties - Configurational Properties - General - set Plattform Toolset: "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)".